# How to check bytes toward the other direction in gdb?

Tags: gdb

`x/4x xxx` will check bytes at higher address than `xxx`.

How to check bytes at lower address ?

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the number of preceding bytes you want from xxx:

```
(gdb) x/4x 0x13b3da00
0x13b3da00: 0x004cc630  0x00000000  0x13af3ba0  0x00000000
(gdb) x/4x 0x13b3da00-4
0x13b3d9fc: 0x00000000  0x004cc630  0x00000000  0x13af3ba0
(gdb) x/4x 0x13b3da00-8
0x13b3d9f8: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x004cc630  0x00000000
```